# Python passing an instance of a Tkinter button into its own command

Tags: python, button, tkinter, command

I am trying to figure out how to pass an instance of a button into it's own command. Essentially what I am trying to do is if the events of the command being called are successful, I want to then disable the button.

Here is my button code which calls a function called 'runcommand':

```
btn_id = Button(tab_id, text=label, anchor=W)
btn_id.configure(command=lambda command=command, logtext=logtext, btn_id=btn_id: runcommand(command, logtext, btn_id))
```

Once called, if conditions are met, I am trying to disable it in the 'runcommand' function:

```
btn_id.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or if I'm just going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing in a reference to the button, so

```
def runcommand(command, text, btn_id):
    ...
    if (should_disable_the_button):
        btn_id.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit confusing. Basically the program is a dashboard to run external commands (batch files, foxpro programs, etc.). The "command" in that case is a value I am pulling out of an XML file which details the external program to call.

Comment: @brianj: I understand. I rewrote the answer after re-reading the question a couple of times. You already have everything you need to disable the button.

Comment: As you can see, I tried to pass the 'btn_id' into the runcommand function I originally posted, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @brianj: if it's not working, you're doing something wrong. This solution is the normal way to do what you want.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I'll take a closer look. I thought it was right. Will report back if I find the hangup.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is where I fully admit I am a dumbass. I was implementing the function correctly. I have an uber complex series of 'if' conditions in the runcommand function and the disable code wasn't getting called. I designated a boolean flag to determine if the button should be disabled now. Works fine. DU...MASS!